# Are there any good tutorials for Facebook authentication?

Tags: facebook, facebook-authentication

I'm linking my app to Facebook, and would like people to log in with their Facebook account, but I can't figure out how to do this.  I had read up on Facebook Connect, but it seems that that's not used any more - but every tutorial I can find seems to refer to it.  When I try to follow them, it doesn't work, because the interface has changed.

Are there any tutorials or guides to doing this the new way?

Basically, what I want to do is this:

> A user who is signed into Facebook and comes to my webpage is automatically logged in to my app (with the usual Facebook 'granting permission' windows etc), or can sign in with their Facebook account if they're not already logged in.
>
> I then want to use Facebook to link users with their friends who are also registered on my site, so they can share things.
>
> I would also like to have access to Facebook comments made on wall posts from my site - so the comment stream for a particular post can be seen on my site as well as on Facebook, and comments can be made on either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some sample apps that do many of the things you speak of are shown [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/samples/). The [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) is probably your best bet right now for delivering the content and access you need and there are numerous tutorials online for how to use it, including the Facebook Developers site itself.

Answer (score 1):

You will find good Tuts on ThinkDiff, e.g.

http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/new-javascript-sdk-oauth-2-0-based-fbconnect-tutorial/

http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/php-sdk-3-0-graph-api-base-facebook-connect-tutorial/

http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/graph-api-iframe-base-facebook-application-development-php-sdk-3-0/

Answer (score 0):

The current method for authentication is OAuth 2.0.

Facebook provides a pretty good outline of what steps are necessary in this Reference:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/client-side/

This example allows the authentication to occur entirely in Javascript on the client side so that you can request a potential user to authenticate via Facebook and then confirm access to your application.

If the user is already logged in, only the access confirmation for your application is performed.

If the user is already logged in and access has already been granted, the user is not required to login, or reconfirm access.